# Matrix multiplication with repeat loop in R

Tags: r

```
repeat_prod_mat = function(mat1,mat2){
  prod = 0
  repeat{
    if (ncol(mat1) == ncol(mat2) & nrow(mat1) == nrow(mat2)){
      prod = mat1*mat2
    }
    else{
      break
    }
  }
  return(prod)
  
}
```

I have to do this with repeat loop but no idea why it won't work.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean - are there errors? If so, what do they say? Does it run forever? Does it return a result that you think is wrong? Do you have inputs that you are testing it on that you can share? For those inputs, what output do you expect? Can you describe in words what it is trying to do?

Comment: `*` is NOT matrix multiplication.